# Error in building wheel for numpy(pyproject.toml) [python 3.10]

Tags: python, windows, powershell, numpy, cmd

This is the error I get:

```
Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml) ... error
     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
    command: 'C:\Users\nazee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 
      'C:\Users\nazee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
     packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' build_wheel 
   'C:\Users\nazee\AppData\Local\Temp\tmptdahv6se'
       cwd: C:\Users\nazee\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install- 
    y927w3wp\numpy_1fd4d3ff2efa4e96877354a794285439
    Complete output (208 lines):
    setup.py:63: RuntimeWarning: NumPy 1.21.2 may not yet support Python 3.10.
    warnings.warn(
    Running from numpy source directory.
    C:\Users\nazee\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install- 
     y927w3wp\numpy_1fd4d3ff2efa4e96877354a794285439\tools\cythonize.py:69: DeprecationWarning:  
    he distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or 
    check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
    from distutils.version import LooseVersion
    Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pxd.in
    Processing numpy/random\bit_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\mtrand.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pyx.in
    Processing numpy/random\_common.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_mt19937.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_pcg64.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_philox.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_sfc64.pyx
    Cythonizing sources
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries mkl_rt not found in 
  ['C:\\Users\\nazee\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 
    'C:\\Users\\nazee\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE
    blis_info:
     libraries blis not found in 
    ['C:\\Users\\nazee\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 
     'C:\\Users\\nazee\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE
     openblas_info:
    libraries openblas not found in 
    ['C:\\Users\\nazee\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 
    'C:\\Users\\nazee\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
    get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 
    'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
     customize GnuFCompiler
     Could not locate executable g77
     Could not locate executable f77
     customize IntelVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable ifort
      Could not locate executable ifl
       customize AbsoftFCompiler
       Could not locate executable f90
       customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
        Could not locate executable DF
       customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
        Could not locate executable efl
    customize Gnu95FCompiler
      Could not locate executable gfortran
     Could not locate executable f95
     customize G95FCompiler
     Could not locate executable g95
     customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
     customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
     Could not locate executable efort
     Could not locate executable efc
     customize PGroupFlangCompiler
     Could not locate executable flang
     don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
    NOT AVAILABLE
     accelerate_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE
     atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    libraries tatlas not found in 
       ['C:\\Users\\nazee\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 
      'C:\\Users\\nazee\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE
     atlas_3_10_blas_info:
    libraries satlas not found in 
       ['C:\\Users\\nazee\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 
        'C:\\Users\\nazee\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE
    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in 
     ['C:\\Users\\nazee\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 
     'C:\\Users\\nazee\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE
    atlas_blas_info:
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in 
    ['C:\\Users\\nazee\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 
    'C:\\Users\\nazee\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE
      C:\Users\nazee\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install- 
      y927w3wp\numpy_1fd4d3ff2efa4e96877354a794285439\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:2026: 
      UserWarning:
      Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
      Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
      A better performance should be easily gained by switching
      Blas library.
    if self._calc_info(blas):
      blas_info:
     libraries blas not found in 
     ['C:\\Users\\nazee\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 
     'C:\\Users\\nazee\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
     NOT AVAILABLE
     C:\Users\nazee\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install- 
       y927w3wp\numpy_1fd4d3ff2efa4e96877354a794285439\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:2026: 
      UserWarning:
      Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
      the BLAS environment variable.
    if self._calc_info(blas):
     blas_src_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE
    C:\Users\nazee\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install- 
    y927w3wp\numpy_1fd4d3ff2efa4e96877354a794285439\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:2026: 
    UserWarning:
      Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
      the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
    if self._calc_info(blas):
    NOT AVAILABLE
    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
    libraries mkl_rt not found in [ 
    'C:\\Users\\nazee\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 
    'C:\\Users\\nazee\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
     NOT AVAILABLE
     openblas_lapack_info:
    libraries openblas not found in 
     ['C:\\Users\\nazee\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 
    'C:\\Users\\nazee\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE
   openblas_clapack_info:
    libraries openblas,lapack not found in 
        ['C:\\Users\\nazee\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 
     'C:\\Users\\nazee\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
     NOT AVAILABLE
      flame_info:
     libraries flame not found in 
     ['C:\\Users\\nazee\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 
     'C:\\Users\\nazee\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
     NOT AVAILABLE
     atlas_3_10_threads_info:
     Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
     libraries lapack_atlas not found in 
     C:\Users\nazee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
     libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in 
     C:\Users\nazee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
     libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
     libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
     libraries lapack_atlas not found in 
     C:\Users\nazee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
     libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in 
     C:\Users\nazee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
     <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
     NOT AVAILABLE
     atlas_3_10_info:
     libraries lapack_atlas not found in 
     C:\Users\nazee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
     libraries satlas,satlas not found in 
     C:\Users\nazee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
     libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
     libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
     libraries lapack_atlas not found in 
     C:\Users\nazee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
     libraries satlas,satlas not found in 
     C:\Users\nazee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
     <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
     NOT AVAILABLE
     atlas_threads_info:
     Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
     libraries lapack_atlas not found in 
     C:\Users\nazee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
     libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in 
     C:\Users\nazee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
     libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
     libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
     libraries lapack_atlas not found in 
     C:\Users\nazee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
     libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in 
     C:\Users\nazee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
     <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
     NOT AVAILABLE
     atlas_info:
     libraries lapack_atlas not found in 
     C:\Users\nazee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
     libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in 
     C:\Users\nazee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
     libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
     libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
     libraries lapack_atlas not found in 
     C:\Users\nazee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
     libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in 
     C:\Users\nazee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
     <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE
      lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in 
     ['C:\\Users\\nazee\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', '  
     C:\\Users\\nazee\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
     NOT AVAILABLE
     C:\Users\nazee\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install- 
     y927w3wp\numpy_1fd4d3ff2efa4e96877354a794285439\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1858: 
     UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
      the LAPACK environment variable.
    return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
     lapack_src_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE
     C:\Users\nazee\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install- 
      y927w3wp\numpy_1fd4d3ff2efa4e96877354a794285439\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1858: 
     UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
      the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
    return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    NOT AVAILABLE
     numpy_linalg_lapack_lite:
    FOUND:
      language = c
      define_macros = [('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_')]
      Warning: attempted relative import with no known parent package
      C:\Users\nazee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: 
    UserWarning: 
    Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running config_cc
      unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
      running config_fc
      unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
      running build_src
      build_src
      building py_modules sources
      creating build
      creating build\src.win-amd64-3.10
      creating build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy
      creating build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\distutils
      building library "npymath" sources
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": 
    https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
    Failed to build numpy
    ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based 
    projects
```

Comment: 'Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/' - seems pretty self-explanatory? :)

Comment: you switched to python 3.10 too soon.  Wait a bit.

Comment: There is no official numpy for python 3.10: use weels: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

Answer (score -2):

The error message tells you:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": 
    https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

Go install the newest version of Microsoft Visual C++ there: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Comment: dors that address the '3.10 is too new' issue that others are having?